# Why can't I access the properties of a PHP DateTime instance?

Tags: php, datetime

If I create and instance of the `DateTime` class, then `vardump()` it:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime;    
var_dump($date);
```

output:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2016-12-22 00:21:21.022426"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

In this case [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is not explicitly reporting that the values of `date` or `timezone` are public, but my experience with `var_dump` is that unless it reports otherwise (i.e. with a label like `[private:date]`), all properties are assumed to be public.
This implies to me that you should then be able to run code like

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime;
echo $date->timezone;
```

and the output should contain the string `UTC` but instead it contains nothing (or more specifically the `NULL` value).

I understand that this is not the correct way to use `DateTime` for retrieving timezone, but having PHP report an object as having public properties that you cannot then access seems to violate a fundamental rule of objects, namely that they hold properties that - if public - you can access them.

Why does `var_dump` report these properties, yet when I try to access them, they evaluate to `NULL`?

Comment: Take a look at [`__debugInfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.debuginfo), it's how `var_dump()` shows properties that do not exist. However `DateTime` is an internal class and might work differently, but this should answer how `var_dump()` can generate 'properties' that do not exist.

Comment: tried `echo $date->getTimezone()->getName()` ?

Comment: @Xorifelse ah thanks, I think I understand. so say for example you wrote a class `MyClass` and you wanted a `var_dump($myclassinstance)` to show "extra" properties that might not otherwise be revealed in a `var_dump` you could use `__debugInfo()` to essentially register those "extra" properties for `var_dump()` to get at?

Comment: @the_velour_fog The returned value from `__debugInfo()` *is* the output of `var_dump()`, so nothing "extra". I wanted to post an answer explaining this, but it was closed.

Comment: @Xorifelse ah ok, I guess you could post the answer on the original question. I just wrote a class using `__debugInfo()` and it behaved as per my comment above. What I didn't expect is that `__debugInfo()` seems to blow away all the normal output of `var_dump()` though.